# Converting CFSocket context to pointer

Tags: ios, objective-c, casting, exc-bad-access, cfsocket

I set the context to the address of the class that created the socket like this:

```
CFSocketContext ctxt = {0, (__bridge void *)(self), NULL, NULL, NULL};

    self.sock = CFSocketCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP, kCFSocketDataCallBack|kCFSocketConnectCallBack, *(CFSocketCallBack)takeCallback, &ctxt);
```

Then in the callback I put this:

```
static void takeCallback(CFSocketRef s, CFSocketCallBackType callbackType, CFDataRef address, const void *data, void *info)
{

PUFTransCont* obj = (__bridge PUFTransCont *)(info);

}
```

I saw Apple sample code that does this and saw samples all over the internet doing this.  Why is it not working when I did it.  Whenever the execution hits

```
PUFTransCont* obj = (__bridge PUFTransCont *)(info);
```

I get a EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code looks OK, but you have to ensure that the `PUFTransCont` object is not *deallocated*
as long as it is used by the callback function.

One possible solution is to keep a strong reference to the object while the socket
is in use (assuming that you compile with ARC).

Another possible solution is to transfer the ownership with

```
CFSocketContext ctxt = {0, CFBridgingRetain(self), NULL, NULL, NULL};
```

(which increases the retain count of the object), and release it later when the
object is no longer needed, for example in the callback with

```
CFRelease(info);
```

Comment: It was deallocated before the callback occurred. I fixed the problem.